# How to retain the Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationData after closing and re-opening the application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I’ve a windows forms desktop application which keeps contact details. The application stores contacts data as below when closing the application,

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationData = mydata;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When application starts it load data as below,

```
      try
      {     
         this.mydata = (DataHandeler) Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationData;

}
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            mydata = new DataHandeler();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            mydata = new DataHandeler();
        }
```

SettingsSerializeAs has been added into Settings.Designer.cs as below,

[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs( System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]

```
public object ApplicationData {
    get {
        return ((object)(this["ApplicationData"]));
    }
    set {
        this["ApplicationData"] = value;
    }
```

But application cannot recover already stored data after each time I close  and re-open the application. Nullreferenceexception is thrown when application trying to load data. How can I recover the data?

Comment: Please define "cannot recover" : is there an exception? What is the Message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an exception being thrown when the settings are saved or loaded?

Are the settings actually being saved to the file?
On Windows Vista or 7, there should be a user.config file in a directory named something like:

> C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\{project_or_assembly_name}\{version_number}\user.config

Is your `DataHandeler` class serializable?

[This MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ddeaca86-a093-4997-82c9-01bc0c630138) might also help.

Comment: Yes, Nullreferenceexception is thrown when trying to load. DataHandeler Class is serializable

Answer (score 0):

after changing your settings  just call the save method in the setings

like  this

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.AppLaststarted = date;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

this will save the app.config files so that it will use new settings.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are 2 kinds of application settings with different scope. User level settings are not saved in app.config file and it is not possible to save Application level settings as I know.

Comment: It has to be a user level setting, because .NET won't make a property setter for it if it is an App level setting, so `Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationData = mydata;` wouldn't compile if it were an App level setting.